# How could I use the TypeScript Compiler API to compile TypeScript to ActionScript 3 bytecode?

Tags: compilers

TypeScript is a superset of ECMAScript and its compiler supports targetting ECMAScript 3; it even supports `yield` and `await` based on host environment's `Promise` and generator interfaces. ActionScript 3 is an ECMAScript 3 subset with only subtle differences such as `Boolean` and `Number` being auto-boxed types, e.g.:

```javascript
new Number(5) === 5 // true in AS3
new Number(5) === 5 // false in JS
```

Other things that come to mind are that class instance methods are bound:

```
class C {
    function f():void {
        this // [object C]
    }
}
var o:C = new C
var f:Function = o.f
f()

var f2:Function = o.f
f === f2
```

The languages ActionScript 3 and Haxe are currently the only languages being used to develop Adobe AIR apps. I don't agree with Adobe AIR API at all, despite it still being alive and maintained by a Samsung company called HARMAN.

The TypeScript's main GitHub repository wiki has a short page on Compiler API, but it does not cover everything. I heard of some existing projects such as typescript-to-lua for the Roblox game, but I don't understand their codebase at all, besides some of the API this specific typescript-to-lua project uses is undefined for some reason and it doesn't seem to be the TypeScript NPM dependency version.

I already know how to output octet streams in general, but I still need to study control flow graph. Other than control flow graph (like translating `break` to jump instructions) and bytecode constant pool, what are the steps necessary to compile TypeScript to something like ActionScript 3 bytecode (aka. AVM2 bytecode)? How do I verify a program (i.e. parse and then resolve symbols and references), make sure there are no syntax or verification errors and transform it into AS3 bytecode?